# callback stays in one ColName for the whole loop

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

so my problom is that the azcolname stays the same for the whole loop for each row
the query looks like that btw i checked that there is stuff to return from data base and that the query is valid

```
 std::vector<PlayerStats> players;
    //get all players in room and scores
    std::string query = "select Statistics.userName, Statistics.getPlayerAverageAnswerTime, Statistics.getNumOfCorrectAnswers, Statistics.getNumOfTotalAnswers, Statistics.getNumOfPlayerGames from Statistics;";
    auto res = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), callback_for_get_players_in_room, &players, nullptr);
    if (res != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__"error sql");
    }
    return players;
```

```
int callback_for_get_questions(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
   std::list<question> *tmp;
   tmp = (std::list<question> *)data;
   question my_question;
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
   {
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "question")
       {
           my_question.the_question = ((std::string)argv[0]);
       }
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "possible_answer1")
       {
           my_question.possibleAnswer1 = ((std::string)argv[1]);
       }
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "possible_answer2")
       {
           my_question.possibleAnswer2 = ((std::string)argv[2]);
       }
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "possible_answer3")
       {
           my_question.possibleAnswer3 = ((std::string)argv[3]);
       }
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "possible_answer4")
       {
           my_question.possibleAnswer4 = ((std::string)argv[4]);
       }
       if (std::string(*azColName) == "answer")
       {
           my_question.correctAnswer = ((int)argv[5]);
       }   
   }
   tmp->push_back(my_question);
   return 0;
}
```

link to pic of the db
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM1mI.png

Comment: Well, you're only examining `azColName[0]`, so it will always be the same. You're doing exactly the same thing `argc` times. Did you intend to use `i` as an index, perhaps?

Comment: BTW: those two snippets don't match – you're passing `callback_for_get_players_in_room` but showing `callback_for_get_questions`.

Comment: molbdnilo thank you iv solved it thanks to you